# How can I encrypt all files with .sql extension using OpenSSL?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I have some .SQL files in specific folder, so I'd like to encrypt them using OpenSSL.

This apparently doesn't work:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -in *.sql -out *.sql.enc -pass ...
```

Comment: Seems like a Linux & Unix question to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Use "find"

OpenSSL is very finicky with its command line parameters. It does not give good error messages at all. And it's easy to mess things up and not notice.

Try this:

#### Generate some input files

```
$ for i in $(seq 9); do echo "This-is-file-#$i." > $i.sql; done


$ tail *.sql
==> 1.sql <==
This-is-file-#1.

==> 2.sql <==
This-is-file-#2.

==> 3.sql <==
This-is-file-#3.

==> 4.sql <==
This-is-file-#4.

==> 5.sql <==
This-is-file-#5.

==> 6.sql <==
This-is-file-#6.

==> 7.sql <==
This-is-file-#7.

==> 8.sql <==
This-is-file-#8.

==> 9.sql <==
This-is-file-#9.
```

#### Store password in environment variable

(I have a bad feeling about this. No idea how bad this is. But this will have to do for this demo. I clean Bash shell command history but I suspect that this is not enough. -- Someone else will have to answer that in another question.)

```
$ export mypasswordvariable='Pa$$w0rd'

$ history -c

$ echo -n $mypasswordvariable | xxd
00000000: 5061 2424 7730 7264                      Pa$$w0rd
```

#### Encrypt

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.sql' -exec openssl aes-256-cbc -pass env:mypasswordvariable -base64 -salt -in \{\} -out \{\}.enc \;



$ tail *.enc
==> 1.sql.enc <==
U2FsdGVkX19njV2FbnxtQNEZfOZM49YmCSYCE4cOeKeLZDrfovbzad+dFoxds+uN

==> 2.sql.enc <==
U2FsdGVkX189IIeDm3mJEA8EG56I/mAzasXrtNhEDY8MT1/IOkHS/WKDHH7h69Fo

==> 3.sql.enc <==
U2FsdGVkX1/y3eRAFIIbsreix9nhpg611t3w0jn19Px8lBTjeE44rItSwwaaCudt

==> 4.sql.enc <==
U2FsdGVkX1/jHEXUfqzr0mdtChCIeQhFpRe+P0cOSeJf0Er96fDKD0nKV0nwPpL3

==> 5.sql.enc <==
U2FsdGVkX1/ask3K8Zt0bgvP/u5SL6hiFBz7u6Msc3LgRQXwa9Qgr4o04A8melkl

==> 6.sql.enc <==
U2FsdGVkX1+YRUF/nBKBdV4XIcyyyZBd7slaXMIQCSIvUnEeSkaR6GPYdE57Z1ng

==> 7.sql.enc <==
U2FsdGVkX1/zJSXlPNNJmMO4dfSqyGkweD+wAftmgOHgpT0NIEoexX0pRKQLPDkR

==> 8.sql.enc <==
U2FsdGVkX1/7i3jxHVTbqjA8JycR0+/46nWpJZHQ9HhGAFjRuszi/YLFe+2cWSMG

==> 9.sql.enc <==
U2FsdGVkX1/Zg7v5fgAJWUuBmb1mz/2cGwTwLSNbTHeSsCs3YtBe1fKpjY5CFIJ/
```

#### Decrypt

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.sql.enc' -print -exec openssl aes-256-cbc -d -pass env:mypasswordvariable -base64 -salt -in \{\} \;
./1.sql.enc
This-is-file-#1.
./2.sql.enc
This-is-file-#2.
./3.sql.enc
This-is-file-#3.
./4.sql.enc
This-is-file-#4.
./5.sql.enc
This-is-file-#5.
./6.sql.enc
This-is-file-#6.
./7.sql.enc
This-is-file-#7.
./8.sql.enc
This-is-file-#8.
./9.sql.enc
This-is-file-#9.
```

Yup. Decryption works.

Comment: +1 for your effort, but I expected one line answer, lol.

Comment: @mirsad why it needs to be in "one line"?

Comment: You don't really need `find` for this, unless you actually need to recurse through multiple directories. For files in a single directory, a simple `for f in *.sql; do openssl enc -in "$f" -out "$f.enc" ...; done` loop would work just as well.

Comment: @mirsad under the big header Encryption you can easily spot the loop "find -type f -iname '*.sql' -exec openssl", which is one line. The answer you got is exactly why i love this site, people that go above and beyond to try and enable the reader to do what they wanted, and more. Things they did not know the program could also do. But if spotting the one-liner was too much effort, trying a few shell loops before asking other people to do it for you probably was too.

Comment: It's all cool. I use these answers to learn the stuff myself. So I made it a full proof of concept. ^^